# Trying to fit a multiple Moyal function in Python with arbitrary curves

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I've been trying to fit a distribution that has multiple Landau peaks (so I'm using scipy.stats moyal). I've tried using scipy curve_fit, but I keep getting errors. The function will have a number of curves to it, designated by "nMIPs." The function is as follows:

```
x = np.linspace(0, len(ADC[0])-1, len(ADC[0]))

def multMoyal(x, nMIPs, *args):
    moy = 0
    for i in range(int(nMIPs)):
        r = 3*i
        moy = moy + args[r]*moyal.pdf(x, args[r+1], args[r+2])
    return moy
```

Where ADC is the spectra. This is particle collision data; it's essentially charged particles passing through a tile in a detector, and each moyal curve is for the number of charged particles (usually somewhere from 2-5, depending on the experimental parameters and the tile location).

The function works fine when I call it like (with nMIPs=2):

```
args = [1, 1, 0.5, 0.8, 2, 0.5]
y = multMoyal(x, nMIPs, *args)
```

But when I try to input it in curve_fit, I keep getting errors ("IndexError: tuple index out of range"). The curve_fit line is as follows:

```
    param, param_cov = curve_fit(multMoyal(x=x, nMIPs=nMIPs), x, y[0], maxfev=5000)
```

Where y[0] is one of the ADC spectra, but smoothed over x to take out the noise.

So, how do I get it to have an arbitrary number of curves and still work in scipy's curve_fit? Or is there something other than curve_fit I ought to be using?

Related: provided I get this to work, how do I also set certain parameters but leave others undetermined? (I want to set the guess for the peak for the first moyal curve and the weight, but leave everything else blank.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but I don't know if it's the right way to do it (but it does work). I updated the function to be:

```
def multMoyal(x, nMIPs, *args):
    moy = 0
    for i in range(int(nMIPs)):
        l = 3*i
        moy = moy + args[l]*moyal.pdf(x, args[l+1], args[l+2])
    return moy
```

Then I added bounds and guesses. Initial guesses for scipy.optimise.curve_fit are all 1, so almost anything you put will be better than that. I picked some ranges that seemed to fit the problem and let it go from there. To set a single parameter (or however many you like), I used bounds. Setting bounds to +- np.inf will leave that parameter free.

For instance, I used a bound for nMIPs from nMIPs to nMIPs+1, which essentially set it at nMIPs (with, of course, a guess at nMIPs). That looked as follows:

```
fitStart = []
startVal = []
weightGuess = []
guess = []
boundsInit = []
boundsEnd = []
for q in range(int(len(ADC))):
    MIPguess = exMax[q][np.where(exMax[q] > exMin[q][0])[0][0]]-10
    starter = int(exMin[q][0]+abs(exMin[q][0]-MIPguess)/2)
    fitStart.append(starter)
    startVal.append(MIPguess)
    weightGuess.append(y[q][MIPguess])
    guess.append([nMIPs, weightGuess[q], startVal[q], 0.2*startVal[q]])
    boundsInit.append([nMIPs, 0, fitStart[q], 0])
    boundsEnd.append([nMIPs+1, np.inf, np.inf, 0.3*startVal[q]])
    for i in range(1, nMIPs):
        l = i+1
        guess[q].extend([weightGuess[q]/l, l*startVal[q], 0.2*startVal[q]])
        boundsInit[q].extend([0, fitStart[q]*l*0.75, 0])
        boundsEnd[q].extend([np.inf, np.inf, np.inf])
```

If I only wanted to set nMIPs, I could have just put all starting guesses at 1 and bounds (aside from nMIPs) to +- np.inf. The fitting was then done as:

```
param, param_cov = curve_fit(
            multMoyal, x[fitStart[q]:], ADC[q][fitStart[q]:], maxfev=5000, p0=guess[q],
            bounds=(boundsInit[q], boundsEnd[q]))
```

It works, but I very much doubt it's the tightest code it could be. I still feel there's some simpler way I'm missing, but this will do for now. I'm curious to see what the experts might answer on this, but I'm putting this down as an answer since there weren't any yet and this at least solves the problem.

Comment: Since no one has commented on this and the solution works, I'm going to accept this answer to close this question. Though this is a bit like talking to myself.